# How to sync animation using turtle-graphics module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have written the following python code to create an animation of a rotating graph using python turtle. The problem I am facing is that, the animation is not properly synchronizing. I don't want to show the people exactly how the thing is rotating. So, I have to carefully choose the frame rate in the `turtle.tracer` command. Well, if you observe carefully, each value of `r` creates a rotation, so I must update the screen at the end of each `r`. And for each value of `r`, there are 1202 iterations inside the loop for `r`. But this does not produce the desired effect.

What must I do to correct this?

```
import turtle
import math

am = turtle
am.ht()
am.tracer(1202,0)

for r in range(0,600):
    #axes
    am.pu()
    am.setpos(0,500)
    am.pd()
    am.setpos(0,-500)
    am.pu()
    am.setpos(-650,0)
    am.pd()
    am.setpos(0,0)
    am.write("0",align="right",font=("Times New Roman",14,"normal"))
    am.setpos(650,0)
    am.pu()
    am.setpos(-300*math.cos(r*math.pi/100),300*math.sin(r*math.pi/100))
    am.pd()
    #axes
    am.pencolor("red")
    for x in range(-300,301):
        g=math.sin(x)
        t=math.cos(x)
        y =100*g*t*math.sin(2*(x**2)*math.pi/100)
        am.setpos(x*math.cos(r*math.pi/100)+y*math.sin(r*math.pi/100),-x*math.sin(r*math.pi/100)+y*math.cos(r*math.pi/100))
    #if(x%4==0):
       #am.write(x)
    am.pu()
    am.setpos(-300*math.sin(r*math.pi/100),-300*math.cos(r*math.pi/100))
    am.pd()
    am.pencolor("blue")
    for y in range(-300,301):
        c=math.sin(y)
        d=math.cos(y)
        x =100*c*d*math.cos(2*(y**2)*math.pi/100)
        am.setpos(x*math.cos(r*math.pi/100)+y*math.sin(r*math.pi/100),-x*math.sin(r*math.pi/100)+y*math.cos(r*math.pi/100))
    am.reset()

am.exitonclick()
```

Comment: What do you want synchronized exactly? If you don't want to show exactly how the thing is rotating, what _do_ you want to be shown? Turtle-graphics is a rather slow way to draw frames of an animation, and it takes multiple seconds to draw each "frame" of your graphic, so producing true animation with it will difficult if not impossible. The "animation" mentioned in the documentation has to do with the speed at which lines are drawn and the turtle is moved (which are all very slow, even when set to be as fast as allowed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following will do what you desire.  I've changed the tracer logic to be more manual with an explicit `.update()` when you're ready to show the user something.  I've also separated the axis drawing from the main loop as we really don't need to clear and redraw it each time:

```
import math
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(0)

# axes
axes = Turtle(visible=False)
axes.pu()
axes.setpos(0, 500)
axes.pd()
axes.setpos(0, -500)
axes.pu()
axes.setpos(-650, 0)
axes.pd()
axes.setpos(0, 0)
axes.write("0", align="right", font=("Times New Roman", 14, "normal"))
axes.setpos(650, 0)

am = Turtle(visible=False)

for r in range(0, 600):

    am.pu()
    am.setpos(-300 * math.cos(r * math.pi / 100), 300 * math.sin(r * math.pi / 100))
    am.pd()
    am.pencolor("red")

    for x in range(-300, 301):
        g = math.sin(x)
        t = math.cos(x)
        y = 100 * g * t * math.sin(2 * x**2 * math.pi / 100)
        am.setpos(x * math.cos(r * math.pi / 100) + y * math.sin(r * math.pi / 100), -x * math.sin(r * math.pi / 100) + y * math.cos(r * math.pi / 100))

    am.pu()
    am.setpos(-300 * math.sin(r * math.pi / 100), -300 * math.cos(r * math.pi / 100))
    am.pd()
    am.pencolor("blue")

    for y in range(-300, 301):
        c = math.sin(y)
        d = math.cos(y)
        x = 100 * c * d * math.cos(2 * y**2 * math.pi / 100)
        am.setpos(x * math.cos(r * math.pi / 100) + y * math.sin(r * math.pi / 100), -x * math.sin(r * math.pi / 100) + y * math.cos(r * math.pi / 100))

    screen.update()
    am.reset()
    am.hideturtle()  # made visible by reset()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Finally, this was likely an error:

```
am = turtle
```

and not doing what you think it was (module name alias instead of an actual turtle.)